# What would be the difference between `git branch -f master HEAD~` and `git reset HEAD~`?

Tags: git, version-control, git-branch, git-checkout

See title really.

Assuming we're already on the master branch:

What would be the difference between `git branch -f master HEAD~` and `git reset HEAD~`?

As far as I can tell both of these commands move the branch/HEAD pointers one up in the commit chain, but are there any other differences between these two worth noting?

Comment: In the first case you would remain on the current branch, while on the second you would switch to `master`.

Comment: Assuming we're already on master. Editing OP to clarify.

Comment: `fatal: Cannot force update the current branch.`

Comment: `git branch -f master HEAD~` gets me `fatal: Cannot force update the current branch.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `master` is the current branch, `git branch -f master HEAD~` refuses to do anything and reports the error *"fatal: Cannot force update the current branch."*

If you are on a different branch, `git branch -f master HEAD~` moves the branch `master` on the first parent of the current branch and does not affect the current branch, the index or the working tree.

`git reset HEAD~` is the same as `git reset --mixed HEAD~`. It moves the current branch on its first parent, updates the index to match the new position of the branch and does not affect the working tree.

As you can see, there are many differences between the two commands.

Please read the documentation of [`git branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch).

**Remark:** *If `git branch -f master HEAD~` would work when `master` is the current branch, its effect would probably be the same as `git reset --soft HEAD~`. We will never know because this form of `git branch` refuses to change the branch that is currently checked out.*

---

The OP asked in a comment: *"I am also aware that mixed is a default for reset but there are also soft and hard but I don't know the differences."*

Scenario:

1. `git checkout master`
2. modify `file1`
3. `git add file1`
4. `git commit`

After this steps:

- `git reset --soft HEAD~1` moves only the `master` branch where it was before the last commit; it brings the repo back to the state where it was after step 3;
- `git reset --mixed HEAD~1` moves the branch and updates the index to match it; it brings the repo to the state it was after step 2;
- `git reset --hard HEAD~1` moves the branch then updates the index and the working tree to match it; it brings the repo to the state it was after step 1.

Of course, this is a simplified explanation and the *"brings the repo to the state"* parts apply only to this simplified scenario. If you `git reset` to a different commit then keep only the explanation about what happens to the branch, the index and the working tree and figure out how the repo will look like after each flavour of the [`git reset`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) command.

Comment: `It moves the current branch on its first parent, updates the index to match the new position of the branch and does not affect the working tree.` I don't understand what this means. Updates index but not working tree?

Comment: I am also aware that `mixed` is a default for reset but there are also `soft` and `hard` but I don't know the differences.

Comment: So `branch` has an implicit `soft` whereas `reset` has implicit `mixed`?

Comment: @user9225276 there is no `soft` on `git branch`. You asked what's the difference. `git reset --soft` moves only the branch and doesn't affect the index and the working tree. `git checkout -f` also moves only the branch and does not affect the index and the working tree. This is where their similarities end. `git reset` operates on the current branch. `git branch -f` refuses to work on the current branch. And `git branch` doesn't have `soft/hard/mixed`. Read about [`git branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch) and [`git reset`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset). They do different things.

Comment: This is incorrect. `git branch --force <branch> <commit>` is equivalent to `git switch <branch> && git reset --hard <commit>`, not `git switch <branch> && git reset --soft <commit>` like suggested in this answer, since `git branch --force <branch> <commit>` *does* affect the working area and staging area by resetting them to `<commit>`.

Comment: @Maggyero Please read the answer again, carefully. `git branch --force <branch> <commit>` does not do any switch/checkout. It does not affect the current branch, the index or the working tree. It refuses to operate on the current branch and all it does is to change the commit that another branch is pointing to. Without `--force`, `git branch <branch> <commit>` creates a new branch (but fails if it already exists) but does not switch to it. It is described in the [documentation of `git branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#:~:text=but%20it%20will%20not%20switch).

Comment: @Maggyero Reformulated the paragraph that probably misled you.

Comment: I think you missed my point, which was that you should replace `--soft` with `--hard`.

Comment: @Maggyero Your point is that `git branch -f` switches the branch, which is not correct. Have you tried the commands described in the answer?

Comment: You are correct about `git branch --force <branch> <commit>` not switching branch. So the command is actually equivalent to `git switch <branch> && git reset --hard <commit> && git switch -` (in my comment I forgot the last switch command to move the HEAD back to its initial position). But my point was that your answer suggests that `git branch --force <branch> <commit>` is equivalent to `git switch <branch> && git reset --soft <commit> && git switch -`, which is incorrect since `--soft` would not reset the working and staging areas to the `<commit>` state.

Answer (score 0):

```bash
git branch --force <branch> <commit>
```

is equivalent to

```bash
git switch <branch> && git reset --hard <commit> && git switch -
```